# Не запускается проект

Tags: c++, qt, creator

господа. У меня такой вопрос: Когда закрываю проект и открываю другой, ранее созданный, компилирую его, qt выдает ошибки, связанные с предыдущим проектом такого рода:

C:\Users\Satan\Documents\QT_Workspace\myWindow\main.cpp:7: error: undefined reference to `Window::Window(QWidget*)'
C:\Users\Satan\Documents\QT_Workspace\myWindow\main.cpp:7: error: undefined reference to`Window::~Window()'
C:\Users\Satan\Documents\QT_Workspace\myWindow\main.cpp:7: error: undefined reference to `Window::~Window()'
collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status

И так каждый раз. Перезапуск QT не помогает. Эти ошибки также являются результатом пересборки открытого проекта. Как это можно устранить? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Build ->clean All  попробуйте

Comment: Не помогает. Только создание нового проекта и копипаст кода

Comment: снести винду и поставить линух, хехе.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант))).
Но я нашёл, в чём проблема. Во вкладке progects, в выпадающем списке Active progects выбрать текущий проект и тогда всё пойдёт, как по маслу.

Comment: Спасибо за участие)))